# Finding least complete solution for congruence

Tags: number-theory

So the equation is x^2 + x + 1 ≡ 0 (mod 21)

I broke it down to x^2 + x + 1 ≡ 0 (mod 3) and (mod 7)

I found the solutions of (mod 3) to be x = 1 (mod 3)

and the solutions of (mod 7) to be x= 2, 4 (mod 7)

The answers on the book as that the solution is  4 and 16 and I have no clue how they got that. Please help. Does it have anything to do with Hensel's Lemma? If so how can I use it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need Hensel's Lemma for this.

Comment: So how would I go about getting the solving the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility: Solve two systems of congruences:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccl} x&\equiv& 1 \pmod{3}\\ x&\equiv& 2 \pmod{7}\end{array}\right.$$
And
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccl} x&\equiv& 1 \pmod{3}\\ x&\equiv& 4 \pmod{7}\end{array}\right.$$

Another possibility: $x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod{21}$ is the same as $x^2+x-20\equiv 0\pmod{21}$.  Now solve by factoring.

Comment: For the second possibility, I'm afraid you'll have problems in in non-integral domain.

Comment: @Bernard: Good point.  It seems that in this particular problem, no extraneous solutions occur (mod 21).

Comment: Yes, but to know that, you have to check  each value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bézout's identity: since $1\cdot 7-2\cdot 3=1$, the solutions for the first system are:
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv {\color{red} 1}\pmod 3\\x\equiv{\color{red} 2}\pmod 7\end{cases}
\iff x\equiv 1\cdot 7\cdot{\color{red}1}-2\cdot 3\cdot{\color{red}2}=-5\equiv 16\pmod{21}. $$

Similarly for the other system of congruences.